# libGDX throwing an error for the default vertex shader in a SpriteBatch

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, game-engine, scene2d

I am new to libGDX and am using it to complete a big game for a school project. I have been following an online tutorial for most of the code, but can't seem to run because of a Vertex Shader error. 
Error:

> Fragment shader:
>       ERROR: 0:1: '' :  #version required and missing.
>       ERROR: 0:7: 'varying' : syntax error: syntax error
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.createDefaultShader(SpriteBatch.java:161)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.(SpriteBatch.java:124)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.(SpriteBatch.java:78)
>       at com.tootireddevelopmentco.games.Splash.show(Splash.java:41)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
>       at com.tootireddevelopmentco.games.RabbitRun.create(RabbitRun.java:17)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:149)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)

I do not have any experiences with shaders, and have not created a shader during my project, or declared a version of any sort. The shader error seems to trace back to the SpriteBatch created in my program. Is there something wrong with my code, or is libGDX and my settings for it the issue.

Some extra code from my classes: 
From the splash class - error points to SpriteBatch declaration.

```
public void show() {
    // apply preferences

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    tweenManager = new TweenManager();
    Tween.registerAccessor (Sprite.class, new SpriteAccessor ());

    splash = new Sprite(new Texture ("img/splash.png"));

    Tween.set (splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA).target(0).start(tweenManager); 
    Tween.to(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA, 1.5f).target(1).repeatYoyo(1, 2).setCallback(new TweenCallback () {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int arg0, BaseTween<?> arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen (new MainMenu ());
        }
        });
```

}

Thanks, 
Julia

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a gles2.0 vs 3.0 issue.

SpriteBatch doesn't support GLES 3 unless you use a GLES 3 compatible shader.

One thing to check is that you do not try and force you libGDX to gles 3.0.

Search your code for `useGL30`(it is called on your `LwjglApplicationConfiguration` object like so `myLwjglAppConfig.useGL30 = false;`), if that is set to true then either remove the line or set it to false.